# Images in spinners

Tags: android, spinner

I have some notification images in my drawable folder that I want to put in a spinner for the user to select, but i cant figure out how to do it with images. I can do text fine but I cant find any sort of tutorial or anything on putting images in spinners. anyone know of any tutorials or anything? i realize I have to override the view of the adapter but im just not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a good tutorial that shows you how to do that. Read this one and the subsequent follow on tutorial and you should be all set.](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/12/custom-spinner-with-icon.html)